# Como implementar o evento do botão close (fechar) de uma tela?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

Quando eu crio uma tela no Scene builder em JavaFX, vem como default três botões no canto superior da tela que são: <kbd>minimize</kbd>, <kbd>maximize</kbd> e o <kbd>close</kbd>.

**Minha pergunta**

Como eu posso manipular e implementar o evento de click do botão <kbd>close</kbd> (X), para que quando o usuário clica-se em fechar eu executasse alguma ação ou método?

Comment: Não querendo ser chato, mas você podia elaborar melhor as perguntas, para que elas não fiquem parecendo vagas. Por exemplo, adicionando um exemplo que já tenha feito ou tentado. Novamente, achei um [**exemplo no SOEN**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13602324/5524514), veja se consegue adaptar.

Comment: Nesse exemplo dado foi criado um botão onde eu aciono para fechar o stage, eu gostaria de saber algum metodo capaz de identificar quando o usuario clicou no botão fechar no canto superior da tela o que já vem default ao criar uma tela no scene builder !

Comment: @diegofm editei a pergunta dele. Bruno veja se a minha edição deixou a pergunta mais clara de acordo com que vc quer?

Comment: Sim, muito obrigado !

Comment: @drmcarvalho ficou ótima!

Comment: Bruno, olha alguma dessas respostas [deste link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22576651/5524514).

Comment: @Bruno você pode criar a pergunta normalmente, mas evite ficar apagando e recriando a mesma sempre, isso pode ser mal visto. Dê uma lida em [ask] para elaborar uma pergunta que seja de fácil compreensão e assim obter uma resposta. E **seja paciente**, as vezes demora a alguém responder mesmo.

Comment: @Bruno, você já conseguiu?

Answer (score 1):

Faz o seguinte:

```
public class SuaClasse extends Application {
    public void start(Stage tela) throws IOException {        
        tela.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                t.consume();

                // Coloque aqui o código a ser executado ao fechar o sistema.

                tela.close();
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dê um id ao botão: `<Button fx:id="fecharTela" onAction="#closeButtonAction">`

Na sua classe que controla a Scene, adicione o seguinte código:

```
@FXML private javafx.scene.control.Button fecharTela;

@FXML
private void fecharTelaAction(){
    Stage stage = (Stage) fecharTela.getScene().getWindow(); //Obtendo a janela atual
    stage.close(); //Fechando o Stage
}
```

Comment: Velasco, Obrigado! estava com a mesma duvida, sua resposta foi simples e objetiva.

Answer (score -4):

```
    id_do_botão.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).